# Pointer to the array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
int (*a)[10] = NULL; // initilaized to NULL pointer

printf("a  :: %p\n", a); // print nil
printf("*a :: %p\n", *a); // seg fault??

return 0;
```

I executed this code on my x86 code using gcc, and it compiles without any error.
I expected something like

a  :: (nil)
Segmentation Fault

but it actually prints out

a  :: (nil)
*a :: (nil)

Why here referencing null pointer does not cause seg fault?

Comment: Dereferencing a NULL pointer is Undefined Behaviour. There's no guarantee that it will result in a seg fault. So you need to adjust your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason in general is that dereferencing a pointer to array does not read any memory, the result is an array having *same address* - the result is just a different type.

The behaviour is undefined nevertheless.

Note that you used `%p` but you could have used `%s` for the second one (with `char (*a)[10] = NULL;`) which  would have even more undefined behaviour, and yet still GCC/Glibc `printf` would **often** print `(nil)` instead of crashing.

Answer (score 0):

That's because this is undefined behaviour, anything can happen on any compiler and even different versions of a compiler.

You are using gcc and the code that gcc generates is merely that it moves NULL (a zero) to rax which does not segfault.

```
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax
```

You can see assembler output for C programs with different versions of gcc at

https://godbolt.org/